# Is it possible to pose as a cleric of a different god?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, cleric, religions-and-deities

Normally for most abilities and spells a cleric must brandish his holy symbol. The symbol itself is intrinsicantly linked to the god he prays to.

Now though in some cases the cleric doesn't want others to know that it is *this* god he prays to. So my question: Is it possible for a cleric to let others believe that it is a *different* god he prays to? (Can he change his symbol so that it looks like one for a different god?)

And if so, what ways are there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As is often the case for Pathfinder *there's an archetype for that*:

### [Hidden Priest cleric archetype](http://aonprd.com/ArchetypeDisplay.aspx?FixedName=Cleric%20Hidden%20Priest)

This archetype allows you to disguise your divine spellcasting as non-divine, even as alchemical tinctures or arcane magic. In addition, it allows you to substitute a far less obvious sign of your faith than a typical holy symbol.

> When the hidden priest uses this ability, he must still provide any divine focus components for the spells he casts. However, the divine focus doesn’t need to be an obvious symbol of his faith. It could be a small coin, tattoo, or garment bearing the symbol, whether presented openly, disguised, or hidden within a larger picture. For example, a hidden priest of Sarenrae may use a coin with an ankh or sunburst, a complex tattoo or scar that has an ankh shape hidden within it, a glove with an ankh stitched on the inside of the palm, and so on. He must use this replacement divine focus just as he would his true one (for example, he couldn’t leave the coin in his shoe).

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer, but I feel like the [Recondite Holy Symbol](http://aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Recondite%20Holy%20Symbol) deserves an honorable mention.